# How to create menu file in solaris

Tags: solaris

Hi I want to create Menu inside Application. Means I want my application should be visible in Application. To achieve this in linux we have to create a menu file. so how to achieve the same in solaris10

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I worked in Solaris 10. But still now facing problem to create .dekstop file. I think the below link may help you. I can not see the icon of my desktop file. Also please read how firefox have implemented for solaris10

http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalID=Q112298

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

This is more desktop environment related than Linux or Solaris.

Solaris 10 is using /usr/share/gnome/default.session when the user choose JDS as its desktop. I'm unsure about what might be used with CDE.

OpenSolaris uses the same method as you know with Gnu/Linux. Just drop the menu file in /etc/xdg/autostart.

Comment: Hi jlliagre, I have created .menu file for Fedora, Ubuntuu, linux mint, Debian, open suse  linux. It worked everywhere. The .menu file creates new sub menu under Application. I want to get the same functionality. I think its linux oriented.

Comment: Again, it is not Linux specific. The way to do it depends on what Gnome release the OS is running.